# Adobe InDesign - Courier Not Fixed Width

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, page-layout

We have an InDesign project on a technical topic. Like many such books, we are using using a variable width font (Palatino right now) for the body text and a fixed width font (Courier) for portions describing source code or system commands.

Strangely, however, InDesign seems to be trying to make Courier a variable width font.

I've included a screenshot from the PDF we've exported from InDesign, but it also shows up as variable width in the InDesign interface itself. Note how narrow the 'i' character is.

[image: courier at variable width]

I have no idea what's going on here or even what to start looking at. Any ideas?

Thanks
Friedman

Comment: a) That doesn't look like Courier to me, fixed width or otherwise and B) the "fi" is a ligature... turn off ligatures.

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing as a ligature setting. Looks like all I need to do is change the Code style such that ligature is turned off. Perfect!

Comment: Thanks @Scott. I'd mark this answered, but I don't think I can do that for your comment. If you submit as an answer I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "fi" is being converted to a ligature. You merely need to turn off ligatures for that paragraph/character style.

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing as a ligature setting. Looks like all I need to do is change the Code style such that ligature is turned off. Perfect!